# When I try to use bodyparser to view the content of my form on the console it does not display my form content

Tags: node.js, express, pug

This is my Pug file
After clicking on the submit button, the contents of my form doesn't show on the console.
Note that I used Pug templating Engine here.
Its actually my first time using Pug.

```
extends layout

block content
  h1 #{title}
  form(method="POST". action='/articles/add')
    #form-group
      label Title:
      input.form-control(name='title', type='text')

    #form-group
      label Author:
      input.form-control(name='author', type='text')

    #form-group
      label Body:
      textarea.form-control(name='body')

    input.btn.btn-primary(type='submit', value='Submit')
```

This is my app.js file.
The route for the form is '/articles/add'.
This is my first time using Pug Temlate Engine.
I don't know if the problem is from my Pug file or from my App.js file.

```
const express = require('express');
    const path = require('path');
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    
    //Connecting our Database
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/nodekb', { 
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,
    });
    let db = mongoose.connection;
    
    //Check connnection
    db.once('open', function(){
      console.log('connected to mongoDB');
    });
    
    // Check for DB errors
    db.on('error', function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
    
    //Init App
    const app = express();
    
    // Bring in Models
    let Article = require('./models/article');
    
    //Load view engine
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.set('view engine', 'pug');
    
    // Body-Parser Middleware
    //parse application /x-www.form-urlencoded
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    
    //Parse application/json
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    
    
    // Home Route
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
      Article.find({}, function(err, articles){
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render('index', {
              title: 'Articles',
              articles: articles
            });
        }
      });
    });
    
    // Add Routes
    app.get('/articles/add', function(req, res) {
      res.render('add-article',{
        title: 'Add Articles'
      });
    });
    
    //Add submit POST route
    app.post('/articles/add', function(req, res) {
     
      console.log(req.body.title);
    });
    
    //Start server
    app.listen(7000, function(){
      console.log(`Server started on Port 7000`);``
    });
```